# Inserir um elemento no inicio e fim de uma lista em prolog

Tags: prolog

quero implementar um programa em prolog que receba uma lista L, um numeor X e um numero Y e insira o X no inicio da lista e o Y no fim da lista (queria uma maneira sem usar o módulo lists do SWI-prolog)

Answer (score 2):

Inserir no início é trivial - `[X|L]`. Isso cria uma lista cuja cabeça é `X` e cuja cauda é `L` (a lista original).

Para inserir no final é necessário percorrer toda a lista, substituindo o `[]` no final por uma lista unitária com o elemento desejado:

```
inserir_final([], Y, [Y]).         % Se a lista estava vazia, o resultado é [Y]
inserir_final([I|R], Y, [I|R1]) :- % Senão, o primeiro elemento é igual, e o resto é obtido
    inserir_final(R, Y, R1).       % Inserindo o elemento Y no final do antigo resto
```